# Routes component not updating on state change, console.log shows opposite of how component behaves

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to install a basic authorization in my routes.  However, I can't even get the component to change when a loading flag is set to true or false.  I am clearly seeing in the console.log that the state is changing, that the loading flag is behaving correctly.  However, inside of the component, the behaviors do not match the exactly what the console.log says.

This is the result of what I am getting

```
routes.js:33 {loading: true, children: undefined}
routes.js:37 not loading
```

This is my component here.

```
const history = createHistory();

function BaseRouter(loading) {
  console.log(loading); //can see props.loading:true in console
  if (loading === true) {
    console.log("loading");
  } else {
    console.log("not loading"); //always comes here
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Grid container spacing={8}>
              <Grid item xs />
              <Grid item sm={8}>
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route exact path="/signup/" component={Signup} />
                  <Route exact path="/userlist/" component={UserList} />
                  <Route exact path="/newuser/" component={NewUserCreated} />
                  <Route exact path="/userupdated/" component={UserUpdated} />
                  <Route exact path="/ticketlist" component={TicketList} />
                  <Route exact path="/createticket" component={StartTicket} />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/ticketdetailview/:id"
                    component={TicketDetail}
                  />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={CreateTicket} />
                  <Route exact path="/mytickets/" component={MyTickets} />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/createdepartment/"
                    component={CreateDepartment}
                  />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/departmentlist/"
                    component={DepartmentList}
                  />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/updatedepartment/:id"
                    component={EditDepartment}
                  />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/updateuser/:id"
                    render={props => <UpdateUser />}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs />
            </Grid>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BaseRouter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument given to a function component is an object containing all the props. You can destructure out the `loading` prop from this object, or you will call the props object `loading` and use that instead which is not what you want.

```
function BaseRouter({ loading }) {
  if (loading) {
    console.log("loading");
  } else {
    console.log("not loading");
  }

  // ...
}
```